# Set a "mailto" address in web.config file of asp.net app?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, mailto

I have a simple landing page on an ASP.NET web app that is supposed to allow the user to email a support center by clicking a link.

Currently, I have two issues: one, the typical "mailto:address" functionality is not working at all.  And two, I've been asked to replace the hard-coded address on the page with a reference to an address that's set in web.config (as we expect the address to change soon).

I have tried the following code in the .aspx file, which results in nothing when the link is clicked:

```
<a href="mailto:support@myorg.org">System Support</a>
```

As for setting the email in the web.config file, I'm not sure what setting can be used to do that at all.

So, expected result: clicking the link opens a new email to our org's support address, which is specified not on the page but as a reference to a system variable (I was told it should be on web.config...).

Actual result: nothing happens at all.

I'm pretty new to this, so any help at all is appreciated.  Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF the link is not working, that is most likely not related to asp.net but to your mail software. Can you click other `mailto:` links?
For the latter, you can add arbitrary settings to the web config and it will roughly look like this

web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="SupportLink" value="mailto:support@myorg.org" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Code:

```
var supportAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SupportLink"];
```

...and then ofc you have to use it. I suggest reading a few asp.net tutorials

Comment: Thank you!  This was enough to get me started. I did have to change my default email client, for some reason...

But also, the appSettings markup was what I was hoping for.  This also helped me: https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Different-ways-to-create-mailto-link---ASP.Net.aspx